# Django: graceful way to deal with missing ID not 404()

Tags: django, redirect

At present, if no project is found, a 404 is raised.
What I would like to do is have the URL do the check but keep on the same page if the input project.id does not exist.

```
def show(request, pk):
try:
    project = Project.objects.filter(
        pk=pk,
        source_language=source_language,
        target_languages__in=[target_language]
    ).first()
except Exception as e:
    raise Http404()
if not project:
    #instead of this do what? print message no project, return to previous page
    raise Http404()
    #return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')) still generates error from non URL match
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, there are a couple of issues with your current code. `filter(...).first()` will never raise an exception, so there is no reason to catch one; and even if it did, you should never catch the base Exception class. Rather, you should use `Project.objects.get(...)` and catch Project.DoesNotExist.

So if you want to swallow that error, you can just return a redirect to the page you want; additionally you can use the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/messages/) to add a message to the user.

```
from django.contrib import messages
try:
    project = Project.objects.get(
        pk=pk,
        source_language=source_language,
        target_languages__in=[target_language]
    )
except Project.DoesNotExist:
    messages.warning(request, 'That project does not exist.')
    return redirect('index')  # or wherver
...
```